# Flatten column as argument

Tags: r, dplyr

When creating summaries of my data using [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html), I often find myself calculating the CI (using [`CI`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rmisc/versions/1.5/topics/CI) from [`Rmisc`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Rmisc)):

```
summary <- data %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarize(
    var1.mean = CI(var1, ci=0.95)['mean'],
    var1.lower = CI(var1, ci=0.95)['lower'],
    var1.upper = CI(var1, ci=0.95)['upper'],

    var2.mean = CI(var2, ci=0.95)['mean'],
    var2.lower = CI(var2, ci=0.95)['lower'],
    var3.upper = CI(var2, ci=0.95)['upper'],

    var3.mean = CI(var3, ci=0.95)['mean'],
    var3.lower = CI(var3, ci=0.95)['lower'],
    var3.upper = CI(var3, ci=0.95)['upper'],

    var4 = sum(var4)
  )
```

This is both painfully verbose and inefficient. Ultimately, I wish I could just write something a bit like:

```
summary <- data %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarize(
    var1 = CI(var1, ci=0.95),
    var2 = CI(var2, ci=0.95),
    var3 = CI(var3, ci=0.95),
    var4 = sum(var4)
  )
```

For the above code, and since [`CI`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Rmisc/versions/1.5/topics/CI) returns a named column with the rows

- `"lower"`,
- `"upper"` and
- `"mean"`,

I wish I could get a data frame with columns looking like:

- `"group1"`,
- `"group2`",
- `"var1.lower"`,
- `"var1.mean"`,
- `"var1.upper"`,
- `"var2.lower"`,
- ...,
- `"var3.upper"`,
- `"var4"`.

Any idea how this could be achieved? Is there a way to "flatten" columns in R? Something like `do.call` but applied like rest as in JS or Python?

There might be something to do using [quasiquotations](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.1.2/topics/quosure), but it starts to go over my R skills..

I used to use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/QuentinRoy/06f607adb503d11ec6862f91af164ac1) with [`plyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr), but it does not work anymore with [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html), and rather than recoding it again, I wish there is a better way than hacking into the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tidyr::unnest` if we format the output as a `data.frame` first

**data**

```
library(Rmisc)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(group1 = sample(c("A","B"),10,T),
                   group2 = sample(c("A","B"),10,T),
                   var1 = sample(10),
                   var2 = sample(10),
                   var3 = sample(10),
                   var4 = sample(10))
```

**General solution**

```
data %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(var1 = list(data.frame(t(CI(var1, ci=0.95)))),
                   var2 = list(data.frame(t(CI(var2, ci=0.95)))),
                   var3 = list(data.frame(t(CI(var3, ci=0.95)))),
                   var4 = sum(var4)) %>%
  unnest (var1,var2,var3,.sep=".")
```

**Result**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 12
# Groups:   group1 [2]
#   group1 group2  var4 var1.upper var1.mean var1.lower var2.upper var2.mean  var2.lower var3.upper var3.mean var3.lower
#   <fctr> <fctr> <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1      A      A    13  56.824819       6.0 -44.824819   11.85310  5.500000  -0.8531024   26.55931  7.500000 -11.559307
# 2      A      B    11  38.265512       6.5 -25.265512   50.97172  6.500000 -37.9717166   25.55931  6.500000 -12.559307
# 3      B      A    11  12.956686       4.0  -4.956686   13.65205  5.666667  -2.3187188   15.07146  5.666667  -3.738127
# 4      B      B    20   8.484138       6.0   3.515862   14.70619  4.666667  -5.3728564   11.31872  3.333333  -4.652052
```

**Or with a custom CI function (same output)**

```
CI2 <- function(x,ci=0.95) list(data.frame(t(CI(x, ci))))

data %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(var1 = CI2(var1, ci=0.95),
                   var2 = CI2(var2, ci=0.95),
                   var3 = CI2(var3, ci=0.95),
                   var4 = sum(var4)) %>%
  unnest (var1,var2,var3,.sep=".")
```

**Or using a converter function (same output)**

can be used with any other functions that returns an array

```
vec2rowdf <- function(v) list(data.frame(t(v))) # creates a 1 row data.frame from a vector, wrapped in a list
data %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(var1 = CI(var1, ci=0.95) %>% vec2rowdf,
                   var2 = CI(var2, ci=0.95) %>% vec2rowdf,
                   var3 = CI(var3, ci=0.95) %>% vec2rowdf,
                   var4 = sum(var4)) %>%
  unnest (var1,var2,var3,.sep=".")
```

Answer (score 1):

The "flattening" is handled by `unnest` (from `tidyr`). You can create a list when summarising and then format with `unnest` so each upper/mean/lower triplet appears as 3 rows:

```
res <- data %>% 
    group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
    summarize_at(vars(var1, var2, var3), funs(list(CI(., ci=0.95)))) %>%
    unnest(var1, var2, var3, .id = 'name')
```

You then need to format your tibble to achieve your desired output by using gather and spread

```
res %>% 
    group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
    mutate(q = c('upper', 'mean', 'lower')) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    gather(var, val, var1, var2, var3) %>%
    mutate(var = paste(var, q, sep = '.')) %>%
    select(-q) %>%
    spread(var, val)
```

It's easy to change this to use other functions in `summarize_*` (to apply different functions to different columns you need to change to `summarize` from `summarize_at` and write out explicitly the expression for each of `var1`, `var2`, `var3`)

Comment: Thanks @konvas. I cannot test it right now but I provided a bit more information, and I'll have a look as soon as I can.

Comment: @QuentinRoy No probs, I've updated the answer to what I think would give you the output you need

Comment: Any idea how I can keep `var4` with this method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible approach, using `unlist` by row after summarising the results for var1-var4:

```
library(dplyr)

summary <- dat %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarize(
    var1 = list(Rmisc::CI(var1)),
    var2 = list(Rmisc::CI(var2)),
    var3 = list(Rmisc::CI(var3)),
    var4 = sum(var4)) %>%
  ungroup()

summary <- t(apply(summary, 1, unlist)) %>%     # unlist by row (this results in a character matrix)
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) %>% # convert matrix back to data frame
  mutate_at(vars(var1.upper:var4),        # convert appropriate columns back to numeric
            as.numeric)

> str(summary)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ group1    : chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
 $ group2    : chr  "d" "e" "f" "d" ...
 $ var1.upper: num  5.77 6.25 5.94 6.49 6.26 ...
 $ var1.mean : num  4.55 4.8 4.66 5.27 4.94 ...
 $ var1.lower: num  3.32 3.35 3.38 4.04 3.62 ...
 $ var2.upper: num  20.5 20.3 20.3 20.1 20.3 ...
 $ var2.mean : num  20.2 19.9 19.9 19.7 19.9 ...
 $ var2.lower: num  19.8 19.5 19.5 19.3 19.5 ...
 $ var3.upper: num  140 155 120 113 141 ...
 $ var3.mean : num  113.9 125.3 94.7 86.3 111.6 ...
 $ var3.lower: num  88.1 95.6 69.9 59.8 82.7 ...
 $ var4      : num  240042 205052 215986 231008 229010 ...
```

Sample data used:

```
set.seed(123)
n = 2000
dat <- data.frame(
  group1 = sample(LETTERS[1:3], n, replace = T),
  group2 = sample(letters[4:6], n, replace = T),
  var1 = rnorm(n, mean = 5, sd = 10),
  var2 = rnorm(n, mean = 20, sd = 3),
  var3 = rnorm(n, mean = 100, sd = 200),
  var4 = rnorm(n, mean = 1000, sd = 5)
)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. So complicated and hard to do for something so simple..

Answer (score 1):

Here is some more concises solutions using the `tidyverse` tools

```r
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(group1 = sample(c("A","B"),10,T),
                   group2 = sample(c("A","B"),10,T),
                   var1 = sample(10),
                   var2 = sample(10),
                   var3 = sample(10),
                   var4 = sample(10))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
```

## First solution

Use `summarise_at` functionnalities by creating a list of function and applying to a subset of column

```r
summarise_fun <- funs(
  mean = Rmisc::CI(., ci=0.95)['mean'],
  lower = Rmisc::CI(., ci=0.95)['lower'],
  upper = Rmisc::CI(., ci=0.95)['upper'])


summary_CI <- data %>%
  group_by(group1, group2) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(num_range("var", 1:3)), summarise_fun)
summary_CI
#> # A tibble: 4 x 11
#> # Groups:   group1 [?]
#>   group1 group2 var1_mean var2_mean var3_mean var1_lower  var2_lower
#>   <fctr> <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1      A      A       6.0  5.500000  7.500000 -44.824819  -0.8531024
#> 2      A      B       6.5  6.500000  6.500000 -25.265512 -37.9717166
#> 3      B      A       4.0  5.666667  5.666667  -4.956686  -2.3187188
#> 4      B      B       6.0  4.666667  3.333333   3.515862  -5.3728564
#> # ... with 4 more variables: var3_lower <dbl>, var1_upper <dbl>,
#> #   var2_upper <dbl>, var3_upper <dbl>
```

That you can join after with a summarise on var4

```r
inner_join(summary_CI, 
          data %>%
            group_by(group1, group2) %>%
            summarize_at("var4", sum),
          by = c("group1", "group2"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 12
#> # Groups:   group1 [?]
#>   group1 group2 var1_mean var2_mean var3_mean var1_lower  var2_lower
#>   <fctr> <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1      A      A       6.0  5.500000  7.500000 -44.824819  -0.8531024
#> 2      A      B       6.5  6.500000  6.500000 -25.265512 -37.9717166
#> 3      B      A       4.0  5.666667  5.666667  -4.956686  -2.3187188
#> 4      B      B       6.0  4.666667  3.333333   3.515862  -5.3728564
#> # ... with 5 more variables: var3_lower <dbl>, var1_upper <dbl>,
#> #   var2_upper <dbl>, var3_upper <dbl>, var4 <int>
```

## Second solution: more concise using functionnal programming with `purrr`

Basically, it does in one block what is done in solution 1. It applies `summarise_at` using argument in list for `.vars` and `.funs`. The result is a list of data.frame that you can combine together with join

```r
library(purrr)
lst(.vars = lst(vars(num_range("var", 1:3)), "var4"),
    .fun  = lst(summarise_fun, sum)) %>%
      pmap(~ data %>%
             group_by(group1, group2) %>%
             summarise_at(.x, .y)) %>%
      reduce(inner_join, by = c("group1", "group2"))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 12
#> # Groups:   group1 [?]
#>   group1 group2 var1_mean var2_mean var3_mean var1_lower  var2_lower
#>   <fctr> <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1      A      A       6.0  5.500000  7.500000 -44.824819  -0.8531024
#> 2      A      B       6.5  6.500000  6.500000 -25.265512 -37.9717166
#> 3      B      A       4.0  5.666667  5.666667  -4.956686  -2.3187188
#> 4      B      B       6.0  4.666667  3.333333   3.515862  -5.3728564
#> # ... with 5 more variables: var3_lower <dbl>, var1_upper <dbl>,
#> #   var2_upper <dbl>, var3_upper <dbl>, var4 <int>
```